# Programa para realizar la media de una serie de tiradas de dado aleatorias mediante funciones

Tags: c, array, funciones

buenas,el programa se basa en realizar una serie de tiradas aleatorias de un dado  yrealizar la media de esta serie de tiradas. El numero de tiradas te lo piden por pantalla. El programa se ejecuta mediante las funciones obtenerRonda y realizarMedia. No se porque pero la media o me da -0.000000 o un numero muy muy grande. Me estoy volviendo locoooooo

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 1000
#define M 6


int obtenerRonda(int tirada[]);
double obtenerMedia(int tirada[],int n);


int main(void) {

int tirada[N];
double media=0.0;
int n;

obtenerRonda(tirada);

media=obtenerMedia(tirada,n);

printf("\nLa media es %lf ",media);


return 0;

}


int obtenerRonda(int tirada[]){

int i;
int n;
srand(time(NULL));

printf("Introduzca el numero de tiradas : ");
scanf("%d",&n);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            tirada[i]=1+(rand()%M);
            printf("   %d   ",tirada[i]);
                        }

         
}


double obtenerMedia(int tirada[],int n){

int i;
double media=0.0;
int suma=0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){

    suma=suma + tirada[i];

}

media=suma/n;

return media;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es que la variable `int n` definida en `main()`, tiene un valor basura, por ende es probable que estés accediendo a secciones de memoria no definidos dentro del arreglo `tirada[]`.

En la función `obtenerRonda(tirada)` pasas como parámetro sólamente el arreglo `tirada[]` que almacenará las tiradas aleatorias de dados. En la función también pides al usuario que defina el número de tiradas, las cuales guardas en la variable local `n`. Recordemos que una vez que la ejecución salga de la función, el valor almacenado en `n` ya no estará disponible.

Las tres opciones que tienes son:

- Definir `int n` como global
- Pasar una referencia o un apuntador a `n` como argumento para `obtenerRonda()`
- Pedir el número de tiradas desde `main()` y pasar dicho número por valor a ambas funciones.

La opción que considero mas sencilla es la tercera. El código entonces es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 1000
#define M 6

int obtenerRonda(int tirada[], int);
double obtenerMedia(int tirada[],int n);

int main(void) 
{
    int tirada[N];
    double media=0.0;
    int n;

    printf("Introduzca el numero de tiradas : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    obtenerRonda(tirada, n);

    media=obtenerMedia(tirada,n);

    printf("\nLa media es %lf ",media);

    return 0;
}


int obtenerRonda(int tirada[], int n)
{
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        tirada[i]=1+(rand()%M);
        printf("   %d   ",tirada[i]);
    } 
}

double obtenerMedia(int tirada[],int n)
{
    int i;
    double media = 0.0;
    float suma = 0.0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        suma=suma + tirada[i];
    }

    media = suma / n;

    return media;
}
```

Notarás que simplemente coloqué el siguiente código en `main()`:

```
printf("Introduzca el numero de tiradas : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

Y además agregué un nuevo argumento `n` a la función `obtenerRonda()`

Ahora, notarás que cambié también el tipo de `suma` a `float`. Esto asumiendo que querrás tener valores decimales en la operación `media = suma / n` (al parecer si porque definiste `media` como `double`). El cambio es debido a que una división entera truncará los decimales.